# If Statement doesn't work when I build my game on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to learn how to develop a 2D game in Unity. I would like to level up the scene when the user completes the scoring task. For example, in the first scene, the user must shoot 5 balls to skip to the second level. I have a score counter which counts down scores.

Here is the related function which I called it in the `Update()` body:

```
    void GetScore() 
{
    if (KickTheBall.timeLeft <= 0 ) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("GameOver");
    }
        else if (ScoreTask <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log (nextScene.name);
        LevelUp ();
    }
}
```

`LevelUp()` function:

```
void LevelUp()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (nextScene.name);
    }
```

On iMac Pro everything works properly, however, when I build it on Xcode, the value of the scoreboard falls below zero instead of skipping to the next level.

These are the log outputs from Xcode:

```
NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.
  at Ball.GetScore () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

-> applicationDidEnterBackground()
```

I think I set all scenes properly:

[image: Please click here to check the scenes]

You can see the scoreboard on the left corner:

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Why it happens only on mobile?

Comment: Are you sure you included all the pertinent files when you moved things to Xcode? The "Filename unknown" comments sound to me like something is missing.

Comment: Yes, I am. I assigned all scenes which are required for the `LevelUp()` function. All scenes can also be displayed any issue on the computer.

Comment: Your error seems to indicate their is not an issue with your Scenes but with your Ball.  You may not be focusing on the right area, if I understand what you've shown us correctly.  But why this works on one and not the other is kind of strange.